# Automatically apply tinymce validation to all drupal pages

Tags: html, validation, drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

I happen to have inherited a drupal project where a common html validation error seems to occur on nearly every page. The validation error is so minor and easy, I actually only have to open any page up in the editor and the tinymce wysiwig editor will fix the problem automatically and I only need to save the page. Considering I will be needing to do this 30k+ times to apply it to the entire site, is there any way to have it either applied automatically to all pages or automated? Any and all suggestions welcome to help me speed up the process.

**EDIT : Used solution**

Since I'm not the most adept at finding a programming solution, I did find an addon for firefox letting me record et loop a series of actions called iMacros. Started it up in 5 different instances of FF and let it running all night and it's half done already. Certainly not the most efficient way of doing things, but may be a solution for those who, like me, aren't as advanced in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can loop through the pages somehow i would suggest to build a page where you include the code source into the editor root html element (textarea or whatever). Then after onInit (see the tinymce configuration options for this (setup parameter and onInit) ) you trigger the submit or save button which delivers the page to the server where it gets saved.
The pages textarea might then get filled with the code of the next page and so on...

The important part here is that your serverbackend is able to loop through the different pages and knows which page comes next when receiving the modified/corrected page code.

Comment: Although I didn't use this solution, it did inspire me to find mine, see edit.